# When passed to an object, will SDL_Surface store a new instance of an image in memory, or point to the image that's passed to it?

Tags: c++, object, pointers, sdl

The Enemy class inherits from the Object class and uses the Object class's constructor to load the image...

```
Object::Object(SDL_Surface *imageFile,int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    image = imageFile; 
}
```

Since I want the level class to handle loading and removing images, I've left the destructor empty for both the Object and Enemy classes...

The level class initializes SDL_Surface for the enemy image and loads the image into it...

```
class Level : public StateManager
{
  private:
  SDL_Surface *enemyImage;
}    
Level::Level(int levelNo)
{
    enemyImage = loadImage("image/enemy.png");
}
```

Then, in the level update function, the enemy image is passed to the Enemy object when its pushed onto the enemy vector...

```
enemy.push_back(Enemy(enemyImage, 640, 200, 32, 32));
```

So, my question is if when the image loaded from the Level object is passed to an Enemy object, is it creating a new instance of it in memory, or is it pointing to the one loaded in the level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you’re doing is copying the pointer to the `SDL_Surface` object; the object itself, and thus the image data, is not reproduced. You should be careful about management of shared resources. In particular, you should ensure that you only call `SDL_FreeSurface()` once for each `SDL_Surface` you load.

Comment: That's the primary reason I wanted to do it this way...When I had the enemy class managing its own image, the game would crash with a segmentation fault when one was destroyed.  I came up with the solution to have the level class manage the images so that SDL_FreeSurface would only be called once when the level ends.  Thank you for the information.

Comment: @user1122136: You could always use `std::shared_ptr<SDL_Surface>` with a deleter that calls `SDL_FreeSurface()`. Smart pointers (`shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, etc.) are generally preferable to raw pointers in modern C++ unless you have a specific reason otherwise.